# Javascript ILLEGAL when generated through PHP

Tags: javascript, php

The following code works:

```js
var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?\nDeleting the category will leave child items without a category');
```

However, when the same exact code is generated through php, it passes a `Javascript Unexpected token ILLEGAL` error... Help?

```
echo "<script>var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?\nDeleting the category will leave child items without a category');</script>";
```

Is it possible to do this without moving into ajax, etc? I already know how to handle the events from the poup, just having some problems getting the confirm box to appear. I could just use a form and get the expected functionality, but I figured a confirm box would be nicer.

Comment: You could just close PHP then re-open it to output `?><script>var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?\nDeleting the category will leave child items without a category');</script><?php`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to double escape the `new line`, once for JS and once for PHP:

```
echo "<script>var r = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this category?\\nDeleting the category will leave child items without a category');</script>";
```